# What does adding two random variables mean?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

In my assignment, I came across with a question asking me that if $X+Y$ is independent of $Z$ if $X, Y, Z$ are three random variables that are pairwise independent. I solved the problem by repeating what the after-class exercise did (comparing probabilities and stuff). But I don't understand the geometric implications, if any, of adding two random variables $X+Y$ together.

In the realm of the real number, adding two numbers is simply manoeuvres over the real number line. But this idea makes no sense in the context of adding random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Remember the intuitive idea of a random variable: It simply chooses some real number $r$ according to a probability distribution.

Consider the random variable $X$ which takes values in $\{1,\ldots,6\}$ based on the roll of a dice.

Consider also the random variable $Y$ which takes values in $\{0,1\}$ based on the flip of a coin.

Then we can consider the random varaible $X+Y$, which takes values in $\{1,\ldots,7\}$ depending on both the dice roll *and* the coin flip.

I'm not sure if there are "geometric implications" (unless your random variables are geometric in nature). Here's an example:

For instance, you could imagine random variables $X$ and $Y$ that each select a random number in the interval $[0,1]$. Then the random variable $\frac{X + Y}{2}$ has some geometric significance: it's the midpoint of the two points you chose randomly.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: What is MSE :(
I encountered this problem in discrete math and completely forgot what I've learnt in statistics a year ago, having no idea why I could get in the university in the first place.

Comment: Math Stack Exchange! It's the website we're on ;)

Comment: Aww, thanks for your answer anyway. I'll try my best to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Sorry - I'm confused now. What would you like clarified in my answer?

Comment: Yeah. I can understand most of your answer. While I'll get to the MSE thing later, I'm still confused about what makes random variables independent or not. Following my assignment question, $X+Y$ is independent of $Z$ while $(X+Y) \mod 2$ is not independent of $Z$. Why does that mod take away the independence? It's not that related to my first question, but I would appreciate if you can give me some hints.

Comment: Intuitively, random variables are independent when the outcome of one doesn't impact the outcome of the other. So for instance, the outcome of a dice roll and the outcome of a coin toss are independent (since knowing you rolled a $4$ doesn't tell you whether you'll toss a heads or a tails).

Comment: Now let's look at the following 3 random variables: $X$ is a dice roll. $Y$ is a dice roll. $Z=X+Y$ is the sum of the two rolls. Now $X$ and $Y$ are independent, since knowing you rolled a $4$ on $X$ doesn't tell you anything about what you'll roll on $Y$. But all $3$ are NOT independent. Because knowing $X$ and $Y$ tells you something (indeed everything) about $Z$.

Comment: You should ask that in a new question so that we aren't discussing it in the comments. Either that or edit this question to clarify that that's what you were asking. I'll happily edit my answer to this question or post a new answer to your new question, but comments aren't a place for long discussions like this

Comment: Yeah, it's getting clumsy. I'm new to StackExchange so I would probably start a new thread once I figured out how to do it. Give me a sec.

Comment: @Meow (Also - if this answered your question you should mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. That way other users know where to spend their time)

Comment: Clicked. Thanks.