# Questions about random variables and modulo

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

In my lecture notes, there is a question about the independence of the random variable.

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent Bernoulli trials each with probability 0.5, and let $X_3 = (X_1 + X_2) \mod 2$.

Show that $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are pairwise independent, but $X_3$ and $X_1 + X_2$ are not
independent.

Credit to @HallaSurvivor for explaining what $X_1+X_2$ means [What does adding two random variables mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924718/what-does-adding-two-random-variables-mean)

I would like to know why $X_3 = (X_1+X_2) \mod 2$ is not independent of $(X_1+X_2)$.

Edit: I often screw up organizing things starting from few weeks ago, apologies for that.

Comment: What is $Y$? $\quad $

Comment: It's $X_3$, got it wrong again. Just fixed it.

Comment: i don't understand.  I thought $X_3=X_1+X_2\pmod 2$, yes?  So, how could $X_1+X_2\pmod 2$ be indepednent of itself?

Comment: I think OP is saying $X_1 + X_2$ is not independent of $X_1 + X_2 \text{ (mod 2) }$. Is that right, @Meow?

Comment: Oh no, I mixed two questions together, give me some time to organize before I ask questions again. Apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Just edited the question, HallaSurvivor is right, that's the thing that confuses me the most.

Comment: What would you think that those variables were independent?  Informally:  knowing $X_1+X_2$ determines $X_3$ uniquely.  More formally, the probability that $X_1+X_2=1$ while $X_3=0$ is $0$ which is not the product of the two separate probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember from your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924718/what-does-adding-two-random-variables-mean/3924730?noredirect=1#comment8093947_3924730) that, intuitively, random variables are independent exactly when information about one doesn't help you predict the outcome of the other.

A classic example is a dice roll and a coin toss. Knowing you rolled a $4$ doesn't tell you if you're about to flip a heads.

So saying that $X_1 + X_2$ is *not* independent of $X_1 + X_2 \text{ (mod 2)}$ is saying that, if I know the outcome of $X_1 + X_2$, I might be able to learn something about the outcome of $X_1 + X_2 \text{ (mod 2)}$. Let's see why:

$$
\begin{array} {|c|c|}\hline X_1 & X_2 & X_1 + X_2 & X_1 + X_2 \text{ (mod 2)} \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ \hline  \end{array}
$$

Each row happens with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ (do you see why?). But look at how similar the $X_1 + X_2$ and $X_1 + X_2 \text{ (mod 2)}$ entries are!

If you know $X_1 + X_2$, then you're guaranteed to know $X_1 + X_2 \text{ (mod 2)}$ as well! (Again: do you see why?)

Since knowledge of $X_1 + X_2$ determines the outcome of $X_1 + X_2 \text{ (mod 2)}$, the two random variables *cannot* be independent. The outcome of one *depends* on the outcome of the other.

---

I hope this helps ^_^